# Unknown file extension .ts when including Server in my tsconfig

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, vite

When I include my server directory in my tsconfig.json and import from a file within the server directory, I get an error (TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"). Not sure why I would have an issue with .ts files when the whole application is TS based. My app runs fine if I don't include the server directory.

I am using VITE and the app is react frontend with nodejs and express backend. Not sure if the issue is related to TS or how VITE works under the hood. The full error is

```
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /Users/**name**/projects/**project-name**/server/database/models/problem.ts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:79:11)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:121:38)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:81:20)
    at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:605:26)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:457:22)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:64:26)
    at #createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:480:17)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:434:34) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
```

My tsconfig.json is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "server"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "**project-name**",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=$PORT npm run dev:seed",
    "dev": "vite",
    "dev:seed": "SEED=true npm run dev",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "vitest",
    "test-ui": "vitest --ui"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "googleapis": "^118.0.0",
    "konva": "^9.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "pg": "^8.11.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-konva": "^18.2.10",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.2",
    "sequelize": "^6.31.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.2",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@types/testing-library__jest-dom": "^5.14.5",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.57.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.57.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vitest/ui": "^0.31.1",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "jsdom": "^22.0.0",
    "msw": "^1.2.1",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.6.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.3.2",
    "vitest": "^0.31.0"
  }
}
```

I have tried googling this problem, but to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't solve the problem, it might put you on the right track.

In typescript, the `tsconfig` file indicates the root of your project and tells the compiler what are the required options to compile the project. See this [tsconfig]: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html made by Typescript. Here you have two options of how to configure the `tsconfig` file in your project.